# The default value of PrefetchCopyIntervalInBytes under x86 and aarch64 is different

Tags: java, jvm, arm, arm64

The default value of `PrefetchCopyIntervalInBytes` under x86 is 576 (9 * dcache_line) while under aarch64 is 192 (3 * dcache_line).
It explains why the default value of `PrefetchCopyIntervalInBytes` is 576 at src/hotspot/cpu/x86/vm_version_x86.cpp

```
// Prefetch settings

  // Prefetch interval for gc copy/scan == 9 dcache lines.  Derived from
  // 50-warehouse specjbb runs on a 2-way 1.8ghz opteron using a 4gb heap.
  // Tested intervals from 128 to 2048 in increments of 64 == one cache line.
  // 256 bytes (4 dcache lines) was the nearest runner-up to 576.

  // gc copy/scan is disabled if prefetchw isn't supported, because
  // Prefetch::write emits an inlined prefetchw on Linux.
  // Do not use the 3dnow prefetchw instruction.  It isn't supported on em64t.
  // The used prefetcht0 instruction works for both amd64 and em64t.
```

But why the default value of this option for arm is not explained.

So how is this value identified for aarch64?

Comment: Interesting question - would be able to provide a bit more context of where the code came from?

Comment: It's from http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/5282d6f65ac9/src/cpu/aarch64/vm/vm_version_aarch64.hpp. I have got a confirmed answer from a jvm developer for arm. The value was identified via benchmark tuning.

Comment: I imagine this will very depends on *which* aarch64 part it is-  this is surely governed by memory architecture of the system